# How to generate image background that flips with each duplication in css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an image

[image]

If I set this image as a background with window being larger than the image,
I get "broken" background, where each picture stands out. Basically that:

[image]

Is there a away to created a continuous background below programmatically, so that the pattern would continue, as the window gets bigger in CSS (just flipping and adding the same image over and over again):

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **You can't.** You can not flip a background image using just CSS.

Possible Solutions for you :

Looking at your problem, if you do not want to repeat your image, then set

```
background-repeat: no-repeat
```

And you can also set

```
background-size: cover;
```

so that the image covers 100% of your container.

And if you want the flipped image at the bottom of your container then edit the existing image in photoshop and use that as the background image.